# Avoiding multiple keys from being pressed

Tags: c#, xna, keyboard, key

I have

```
var newkbState = Keyboard.GetState(); 
newkbState = GetKeysPressedBetween(oldkbState, newkbState); 
Keys[] pressedKeys = newkbState.GetPressedKeys();

if (newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.LeftShift) || newkbState.IsKeyDown(Keys.RightShift))
{
    shiftNew = true;
}
else
{
    shiftNew = false;
}

newInput = "";

for (int count = 0; count < pressedKeys.Length; count++)
{
    newInput += ConvertKeyToChar(pressedKeys[count], shiftNew);
}

if ((newInput != oldInput) && (newkbState != oldkbState))
{
   text2 += newInput;
}

oldInput = newInput;
oldkbState = newkbState;

KeyboardState GetKeysPressedBetween(KeyboardState first, KeyboardState second)
{
   KeyboardState pressed = new KeyboardState();
   for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
   {
      FieldInfo currentStateI = typeof(KeyboardState).GetField("currentState" + i, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
      uint firstCurrentStateI = (uint)currentStateI.GetValue(first);
      uint secondCurrentStateI = (uint)currentStateI.GetValue(second);
      currentStateI.SetValueDirect(__makeref(pressed), ~firstCurrentStateI & secondCurrentStateI);
   }
   return pressed;
}
```

Alright so, I'm having problems. What's happening is:

1. Just tapping the letter <kbd>A</kbd> once outputs 3 a's.
2. When two buttons are pressed, <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>B</kbd>, the first problem happens and `abababababab` just keeps repeating as I hold onto it.

If I fix the first problem, I'm not sure if the second would fix.
Can anyone fix my code or recommend a fix please? Or at least find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I can think is that you should detect the pression of a key only when you release it, in this way you ensure that each key is detected only once.
Or you can detect the key pression and then stop "reading" it using a boolean. When you release the key the boolean changes state.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to detect new key presses; i.e when you press and hold <kbd>a</kbd> you only react to the "a" once despite your code flagging it as being held down every frame.

An extremely helpful and simple method that you should implement somewhere is:

```
bool IsNewKeyPress(Keys key)
{
    return oldInput.IsKeyUp(key) && newInput.IsKeyDown(key);
}
```

Depending on where you put this, you may need to also provide the method with your new and old keyboard states.

Usage is also simple. In your method that works out a `Key[]` of new key presses, you instead want to enumerate over each `Key` in `newInput.GetPressedKeys()`, i.e:

```
List<Key> keys;
foreach (Key key in newInput.GetPressedKeys())
{
    if (IsNewKeyPress(key))
        keys.Add(key);
}
return keys.ToArray();
```

Or if you like LINQ:

```
var newKeys = input.GetPressedKeys();
Key[] keys = newKeys.Where(key => IsNewKeyPress(key)).ToArray();
return keys;
```

Not at my PC, so may have used a wrong method name, but you get the picture!